# How to Run pinax inside eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pinax

i have been trying to running some pinax code inside pydev eclipse

i keep on having this error

Error: Can't import Pinax. Make sure you are in a virtual environment that has Pinax installed or create one with pinax-boot.py.

my question is how do i run pinax inside eclipse using django built in server

i am python newbie

Comment: what i want to do is using django built in server ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this: http://pinaxproject.com/docs/0.7/install.html

make sure you set the virtual env right

Answer (score 0):

First you install pinax and create a project as instructed at the site http://www.slideshare.net/davidpaccoud/introduction-pinax

Then create a django project in eclipse, after that import created pinax project into the djnago project in eclipse by clicking on File -> import. It'll ask for path of source(pinax project) and destination(eclipse project). Complete this process and you'll be able to handle your whole pinax project from eclipse.